# Null Pointer Exception while Retriving Data from Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am retrieving data from sqlite to base adapter by cursor.

main.java

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from budget",null);
      while (c.moveToNext()) {



        String tes0 = Integer.toString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        String tes1 = Double.toString(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("material_actual")));
        tes2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("start_date"));
        tes3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("end_date"));

        String[] v0 = new String[] { tes0 };
        String[] v01 = new String[] { tes1 };
        String[] v02 = new String[] { tes2 };
        String[] v03 = new String[] { tes3 };

            Adapter_ListView adapter = new Adapter_ListView(getBaseContext(),
                v01, v02 , v03, theTotal); //string[]
            TaskList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Then, Adapter_listView.java

```
public class Adapter_ListView extends BaseAdapter {
private int count;
private Context context;

private String[] string1;
private String[] string2;
private String[] string3;

private String con1;
private String con2;
private String con3;


public Adapter_ListView(Context baseContext, String[] v01, String[] v02, String[] v03, int theTotal) {
       this.count   = theTotal;
       this.context = baseContext;
       this.string1 = v01;
       this.string2 = v02;
       this.string3 = v03;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_inflate_list2, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.inflate_title);
    TextView body = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.inflate_body);
    TextView sub = (TextView)contentView.findViewById(R.id.inflate_sub);


    title.setText(string1[position]);
    body.setText(string2[position]);
    sub.setText(string3[position]);


    return contentView;
}
}
```

from this code always error --> ArrayOuOfBound if execute this code

```
title.setText(string1[position]);
```

how i can solve it?

Comment: Wait, so do you have a null pointer exception or an ArrayOutOfBounds exception?

Comment: Did you get any of value from local DB . Mean you get value in v0,v01... ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open your database in the activity you retrieve or insert data into your `SQLite database`. Also make sure you close it when your finished.

```
final DatabaseHelper m = new DatabaseHelper(this);
 m.open();
```

In your onDestroy or pause. Call

```
m.close();
```

This may be the issue, because i dont see where you open your database in the code.

**EDIT :**

In your `DatabaseHelper` class. Create a method.

```
public void open(){
db.open();
}

public void close(){
db.close()
}
```

Then you will have the method to close and open the database in your activities where you need to insert and retrieve information.

Answer (score 1):

To retrive data from cursor, first you must go to first row data in cursor.

Some code like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from budget",null);
if (c!=null) c.moveToFirst();
      while (c.moveToNext()) {
...
}
```

good luck!! :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to load resultset into list, if so please change your code to set adapter outside of loop:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from budget",null);
int theTotal=c.getCount();
 String[] v0 = new String[theTotal];
        String[] v01 = new String[theTotal];
        String[] v02 = new String[theTotal];
        String[] v03 = new String[theTotal];

      int i=0;
      if (c!=null) c.moveToFirst();
      while (c.moveToNext()) {



        String tes0 = Integer.toString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        String tes1 = Double.toString(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("material_actual")));
        tes2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("start_date"));
        tes3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("end_date"));

        v0[i] =tes0 ;
        v01[i] = tes1 ;
        v02[i] = tes2 ;
        v03[i] = tes3 ;



}

Adapter_ListView adapter = new Adapter_ListView(getBaseContext(),
                v01, v02 , v03, theTotal); //string[]
            TaskList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**main.java**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from budget",null);
if(c.getCount()>0)
{
    int i=0; 
    int clength=c.getCount();
    String[] v0=new String[clength];
    String[] v1=new String[clength];
    String[] v2=new String[clength];
    String[] v3=new String[clength];

    while (c.moveToNext()) 
    {        
        String tes0 = Integer.toString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        String tes1 = Double.toString(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("material_actual")));
        tes2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("start_date"));
        tes3 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("end_date"));

        v0[i]=tes0;
        v01[i]=tes1;
        v01[i]=tes2;
        v01[i]=tes3;
        i++;    
    }
    Adapter_ListView adapter = new Adapter_ListView(getBaseContext(),v01, v02 , v03, theTotal); //string[]
    TaskList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```